# Google Script IF Statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can someone help me to convert the below condition to Google Script?

I have Column A and Column B and I need to get result in Column C.

Condition:

```
 If A="Good" and B="5star" then C="OK"
 If A="Fair" and B="5star" then C="OK"
 If A!="Fair" or A!= "Good" and B="1star" then C="OK"
 all other cases should be "NOK"
```

Note: `!=` means not equal I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular `if/else if` statements but I think [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) are cleaner:

```
function myFunction(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vals = sh.getRange("A2:B"+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const cvals = []; 
  vals.forEach(r=>{           
     cvals.push( [
        ["Good","Fair"].includes(r[0]) && r[1]=="5star" || 
        !["Good","Fair"].includes(r[0]) && r[1]=="1star"?"OK":"NOK" 
     ])            
  });
  sh.getRange(2,3,cvals.length,1).setValues(cvals);   
}
```

With an `if` condition, it would be:

```
function myFunction(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vals = sh.getRange("A2:B"+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const cvals = []; 
  vals.forEach(r=>{           
     if(["Good","Fair"].includes(r[0]) && r[1]=="5star" || 
        !["Good","Fair"].includes(r[0]) && r[1]=="1star")
     {cvals.push(["OK"])}
    else{cvals.push(["NOK"])};               
  });
  sh.getRange(2,3,cvals.length,1).setValues(cvals);   
}
```

And here is how you can get the columns separately in case you have a non-contiguous range:

```
function myFunction(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const col1 =  sh.getRange("A2:A"+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const col2 =  sh.getRange("B2:B"+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat(); 
  const cvals = []; 
  col1.forEach((_,i)=>{           
     cvals.push( [
        ["Good","Fair"].includes(col1[i]) && col2[i]=="5star" || 
        !["Good","Fair"].includes(col1[i]) && col2[i]=="1star"?"OK":"NOK" 
     ])            
  });
  sh.getRange(2,3,cvals.length,1).setValues(cvals); // 2 means second row, 3 means column C
}
```

Comment: Hello Marios, I am noob for google script, slowly I am learning, Can you please suggest me what is the road map to learn app script please?

Comment: I find simple `if/else` easier/faster to comprehend/maintain than chained ternaries.

Comment: @JavaScript true, it might be more convenient for some cases. Also, I just realized that chained ternaries are not required in this case. Please check my updated code.

Comment: @Moses I would suggest you to learn some JavaScript first. See [starting point here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp). And then after you get familiar with JS you can go to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) (or watch some youtube videos).

Comment: @Marios, thank you and sorry for asking you another question, 
Can you please split column A and B? So I will use it accordingly I need.
In the script A and B is called joined A2:B, Separately I need, Please